# How to convert a txt file to shp?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I've got a txt/csv file with the utm coordinates and the hights. Now I want to upload this into qgis. This is not a problem so far. The problem is to create a shapefile out of the data with an attribute table for adding other values to work with. Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rightclick -> Save as ...` to a shapefile should not be a problem. Then you can add additional columns to the attribute table of the shapefile with `Table manager` plugin or field calculator in the attribute table.

If you want to keep the attributes in a separate table outside QGIS, you need a common id field, with which you can join shapefile and external table data.

You can add the data table with `Add vector layer` (which does not sound logical for non-vector data) and define a join in the properties of the shapefile layer.

Answer (score 6):

There's a plugin called **Add Delimited Text Layer.** I believe it is included in a default 1.8 install. Once the plugin is enabled, an option appears in the Layer toolbar and menu, where the Add Vector, Add Raster, etc. options are. The wizard should be self-explanatory, but feel free to ask further if you experience issues.

An imported text file still can't be edited by QGIS. Once you've imported the layer, you can use **Layer > Save As...** to save a shapefile, or any other format. Save the shapefile and then import it into QGIS, and you can edit as normal.

Full help [here](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/01/importing-spreadsheets-or-csv-files-to.html).

Comment: FYI Add Delimited Text Layer is now core and no longer a plugin.

Comment: @NathanW, do you mean that the user no longer has to enable it in the plugin manager? Do you know which version this changed in?

Comment: It will be in 2.0 once it comes out.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ogr for this, see [this](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html). In essence, this is what you need (from that previous link)

Consider the following CSV file (`test.csv`):

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name
48.1,0.25,"First point"
49.2,1.1,"Second point"
47.5,0.75,"Third point"
```

You can write the associated VRT file (`test.vrt`):

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test">
        <SrcDataSource>test.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

You might need to change the LayerSRS to your UTM, but you get the idea: `test.vrt` can be opened by OGR, QGIS, etc. You might even convert it to another format (Shapefile, whatever) using `ogr2ogr` for example!